# Intuition for resolutions of operads

Tags: model-categories, operads

Is there an intuitive way to understand resolutions of operads for someone not well-versed in model categories?  In particular, I'd like to have some idea, even if not a complete understanding, of how the various $A_\infty$-operads (for example, the Stasheff operad) arise from the associative operad in different categories, but at present I don't really have any feel for what a cofibrant operad looks like.